# Rails, test a "routes.rb" level redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, testing, routes

I have this redirect defined in my `routes.rb`:

```
# routes.rb
get "/my/route/one", :to => redirect { |params, request| "/my/route/two" }
```

How can I make a test to cover this set up?